# Elastic-search search with both should and must

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I need to search products with must and should.
Example query: black men jeans.
I have field gender so gender = men are must. remaining query go to other fields like title and description. Can somebody help me with this to form a query?

```js
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [{
        match: {
          title: {
            query: search_term,
            boost: 5,
            analyzer: 'my_analyzer',
            minimum_should_match: '80%',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        match: {
          queries: {
            query: search_term,
            boost: 10,
            minimum_should_match: '90%',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        match: {
          gender: {
            query: gender,
            boost: 8,
            minimum_should_match: '100%',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        match: {
          color: {
            query: color,
            boost: 5,
            minimum_should_match: '100%',
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried this but not working. Can somebody how can I make it better for search.

Comment: Please add to you question whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve your requirements:

```
GET <indexname>/_search
{

  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": 
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "geneder": "men"
          }
        },
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "diesel"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description": "Strechable denim jeans for men"
          }
        }],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```